How to check if the first /r/ or /j/ sound is elided in "February"?
I've just learnt that there is more than one way to pronounce the word "February":

/ˈfebyuˌweri/
/ˈfebuˌweri/
/ˈfebruˌweri/

And some other variations with /u/ being reduced to schwa.
Following this, I checked the dictionaries to see which one is more popular. But upon hearing the recording on Cambridge Online Dictionary, I found it really difficult to know which version is being used. Here's the link for the sound.
I know some basic acoustic analysis but not helpful enough to detect which sonorant is being used or elided.

Most people would not have a /w/ in there in regular speech. In BrE, /ˈfεbrʊəri/ is common, and in both AmE and BrE, /ˈfεbrəri ~ ˈfεbrʊri/ or just /ˈfεb(ə)ri/ is even more common. The full /ˈfεb(r/j)uˌε(ə)ri/ is often limited to careful or speech, and /ˈfεb(r/j)uˌwε(ə)ri/ would be most likely in very emphatic, over-enunciated speech. The recording you link to is an example of very careful speech, saying /ˈfεbruˌεri/, but the difficulty in distinguishing all those /r/’s and /w/’s next to a /u ~ ʊ ~ ə/ is exactly why there’s so much variation in the pronunciation.

The link clearly gives /ˈfebruˌweri/ but that will not be obvious to most non-native speakers… which is why I ask what your own native tongue is, please?
Many, if not most Asians - a huge portion of the people on Earth - are literally unable to interpret that 'r' sound, even if they can physically hear it.

@RobbieGoodwin my first language is Vietnamese.

Thanks and can you say whether generally, Vietnamese speakers recognise all sounds in the same way English people do? (By 'English people' I mean not international or even British native speakers but literally people born, bred and taught the language in England. May we leave the rest aside for clarity, or do you see this topic as necessarily including all varieties of English?
Does /ˈfebruˌweri/ work for you, please?
Back at the OQ, where is there a /j/ sound in 'February'?
Doesn't a /j/ sound suggest something like /ˈfebjuˌweri/?

@RobbieGoodwin I do, though I'm not sure others. The sequences/br/, /bj/ don't exist in our sound inventory. I don't think the varieties is relevant much in this case, just want to know where /r/ or /j/ is the correct phoneme for the recordings there (irrelevant since they're phoneme in all varieties of English).

If you're sure you recognise sounds the same way English people do, what are you Asking, please?
In 'February…'  /br/ is correct, /bj/ is wrong and /by/ is such a common misuse that anywhere other than in a study of phonetics as used in linguistics, it might as well be correct.
All that aside I suggest it matters, neither /br/ nor /bj/ is anything like a 'sequence'.

@RobbieGoodwin, but I cannot tell the difference in complicated settings such as one that involving dissimilation, which might occur in those recordings.

That you 'cannot tell the difference in complicated settings such as one that involving dissimilation, which might occur in those recordings…' says what about the Question, which I thought was 'How to check if the first /r/ or /j/ sound is elided in "February"?'
It remains the case that /ˈfebruˌweri/ is correct and anyone suggesting anything different is misleading you.
Why is that hard to accept?

@RobbieGoodwin I want to know a method to check the existence or nonexistence of that sound not relying on any specific person's ears. So, it helps for people who can't distinguishing the difference between those sequence, i.e. /bru/ and /bu/.

I'm sorry I didn't make this clear earlier and your Question simply can't work.
There is more than one way the word 'February' is commonly pronounced but only the listener's ears can tell whether a particular speaker elides the first /r/ or /j/ sound.
In your examples only /ˈfebruˌweri/ is correct; /ˈfebyuˌweri/ and /ˈfebuˌweri/ are both strictly wrong, but nevertheless so common, they might be heard every day.
